# How to set the number of item per page in a Drupal View?

Tags: drupal, pagination, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a problem at which I have a view that will display a featured item and 6 rows on the first page of the view, while displaying 9 rows on the rest of the pages. Is such a functionality possible with views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few methods I can think of. I have mentioned them on the basis of how long it will take you.

1) Create a custom css rule which hides two entries on the first page. As for the rest of the pages you can show it.

2) Find the template file of your particular views and then use php to hide those rows. You can find the name of this file in your views theme section.

3) You could  write a php  module which can do the same as views. Its not that hard to get it done.

**UPDATE**

Below is the jquery which will help you get the logic right

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

// here we assignt he current url of the page to the var pathname
});

if(pathname =='firstPageofView')
{
// if the path name is the first page of the view then we assign special css formating
$('#divid').hide(); 

}
else
{

$('#divid').css('width','10px');    
}
```

Cheers,
Vishal

Comment: Hiding with css and in the template file doesn't appear like an option since I won't be able to reprint the hidden rows again. Do you have an example of the module which implements paging differently on the first page?

Comment: Please give full details as to what your view does and I will hack something  up  for you.

Comment: Well I have content type articles. The first record will be displayed differently (Big Image and the length of the body is bigger) than the rest and it will occupy the space of 3 normals records. The first page will have one big record, and six normal records. The rest of the pages will occupy 9 normal records. This screenshot better explains what I am talking about http://i44.tinypic.com/oa7j3m.png .

Comment: after seeing your layout and your requirement I suggest you use jquery to get the formatting done. Its a waste to make a module for this in my opinion.

Comment: I have added the jquery logic in my answer

Comment: vishal, this simply won't work. The problem here is not width, it is the number of records per page. That's it.Forget about my specific example, how do you show 6 records on the first page and 9 records on the rest.

Comment: its the same logic instead of using width use .hide()

Comment: This wouldn't work my friend, where would the hidden rows go! in the first page you need to show rows 1-6 , in the second page you need to show the rows from 7-15 , in the third 16-24 .... there is no place for hiding rows.

Comment: sorry got me self confused there for a while you will need to make a module for the said. Try this question in views support forum and see what they have to say abt it